# How to resolve promise and spy on a function inside axios

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs, axios-mock-adapter

```
function getusers(config){
     const {successCB} = config;
     return axios.get(url, params)
      .then(response => {
        successCB(response.data, config);
      });
}

************************ UT ******************************

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
const successCB = jest.fn();

mock.onGet(url).reply(200, 'success');
const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
const successCBSpy = jest.spyOn(config, 'successCB');

getUsers({successCB});
```

axiosSpy is success from below code

```
expect(axiosSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But it's not reaching inside to resolve with results for successCB

```
expect(successCBSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Throwing error as: `successCB` never called

What am I doing wrong and what should I expect here?

I am only able to use ES6 solutions only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you return the `Promise` from `getusers` so you can `await` it in your test.

Here is a complete working example:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');

const url = 'test-url';
const params = {};

function getusers(config) {
  const { successCB } = config;
  return axios.get(url, params)  // <= return the Promise
    .then(response => {
      successCB(response.data, config);
    });
}

test('getusers', async () => {  // <= async test function
  const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
  const successCB = jest.fn();

  mock.onGet(url).reply(200, 'success');
  const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');

  await getusers({ successCB });  // <= await the Promise

  expect(axiosSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  expect(successCB.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('success');  // Success!
})
```

**Update**

If `async/await` syntax is not an option then you can do the assertions in a `then` callback and return the resulting `Promise` from the test so `Jest` knows to wait for it:

```js
test('getusers', () => {
  const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
  const successCB = jest.fn();

  mock.onGet(url).reply(200, 'success');
  const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');

  return getusers({ successCB }).then(() => {
    expect(axiosSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
    expect(successCB.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('success');  // Success!
  });
})
```

Comment: now the successCB has been defined as jest.fn() in our code and our project is not supported with ES7. Any chance to resolve it using ES6 ?

Comment: @Mithun I just provided the general idea of what you need to do.  If you update your question with your actual test code I'll update my answer based on the code you share

Comment: @ brian-lives-outdoors - updated my question, please have a look

Comment: @Mithun I updated my answer with a complete working example

Comment: async, await is not supported in our application @brian

Comment: `Promise { <pending> }` i see this as the promise not being resolved. I am wondering if there is a way to reolve the promise using spy in jest, similar functionality was present in jasmine karma when working with angular

Comment: @Mithun I added an example for testing without using `async/await` syntax

Comment: Almost in the last phase, ill accept the answer. One last thing successCB is a callback function passed to getUsers. So, i am not able to expect the response result of `success` from `successCB`. Could you please tweak a little. Ill close this question

Comment: @Mithun I just add those comments as a way to indicate the test passes, but sure, I can remove them

Comment: `expect(successCB).toHaveBeenCalledWith('success'); ` throws as error like `undefined`

Comment: @Mithun ah, I get what you are asking now.  Remove `config` as the second argument to `successCB` in `getusers`.  I've updated the code and tests in my answer

Comment: I am sorry, we can't remove the second argument. `Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received the object.` // its comparing `empty object {}` with `string success`. should we change the success callback implementation of mock.jest.fn() ? is what I am thinking

Comment: @Mithun k, then you can check **just the first argument** that the callback was called with by using [`mockFn.mock.calls`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls).  Answer updated.

Comment: Brilliant, i learnt something new from you today, thanks @brian

Comment: @Mithun glad I was able to help!